# always first selectet in row boxlist with filterlist.js

Tags: javascript, django, html-lists, row, html-select

I have a list, created like this:

```
    <label>
    <select class="select" name="myselect" size="20" required="true">
        {% for row in rows %}
        <option class="{% cycle 'eins' 'zwei' %}">{{ row|cut:"'"|cut:"("|cut:")" }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
    </label>
```

now i have used this javascript: [filterlist.js](http://www.barelyfitz.com/projects/filterlist/)

my following code looks like this:

```
    <SCRIPT TYPE="text/javascript">
            <!--
            var myfilter = new filterlist(document.myform.myselect);
            //-->
</SCRIPT>
        <P>Count: {{ rows|length }}</P>
        <P>Previously set filter from the first page: "{{ form1 }}"</P>

        <label>
        <INPUT class="input" NAME= regexp onKeyUp="myfilter.set(this.value)">
        </label>
        <INPUT class="senden" TYPE=button onClick="myfilter.reset();this.form.regexp.value=''" value="Clear">

        <INPUT TYPE=HIDDEN NAME="sef" VALUE="">

    <input  class="senden" type="submit" name="send" href="kundendaten" value="Send">
```

all works without troubles...

when i fill in now selected="selected" in the option of select, the last one will be selected. when i use then the filter (fill in letters) the list has no more 7k data lines or more... but the select isnt there anymore. :(

now my two questions:

1. How can i set always the first and not the last as selected?
2. How can i hold the select after using the filter? (i will always have the first selected)

have i to change anything in this javascript or is there a simple trick for my own code?

I use win7 32bit, python 2.7.3, django 1.4.1, html5 and css3

Comment: It is hard for me to tell what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I try to complain it clearlier: I produce the boxlist with this... {% for row in rows %}
when i add now: <option selected="selected" class=... i have always the last one selected of my row. how can i select the first?

Comment: and for the second part, when i use this js, begin with this filter... no line is selected after using. but i will have selected ALWAYS the first. (sry for my bad english) ^^

Answer (score 0):

I did not found the correct answer, but with this filterlist js it is better to set the input field as active...

HTML:

```
    <label>
        <input id="select" name="variable" class="input" size="25" maxlength="9">
    </label>
```

JS:

```
$('input[id="select"]').focus();
```